# Using ImageIcon in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

So I have this code and for quiet a while I was wondering what the problem was in the code for it to not display..and then I found it it displays perfectly well in JGrasp so it just a intellij problem.

Why does it not work in inintellij when the images aren't even in a sub-folder but just sprayed out everywhere in the folder?

**EDIT:** By the way I know its probably due to Intellij not using it as a resource or something but its literally in the same spot as the source file so I don't get it :/

**NOTE:** In the picture, Icon is so Intellij can use it as a resource. Other things was what it looked like before

What would be the way to implement this in intellij as all the other answers I have seen are people using the direct path or something else so I'm not sure how it would work with getImage()

**Note** this is an **Applet Application** and there is a display line somewhere in my code

```
image1 = new ImageIcon(flag1);
l1 = new JLabel(image1);
flag1 = getImage(getCodeBase(),coun.countryLst[0].getcountryFlag());
```

Also heres a picture of the folder things are saved at

[the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsNKV.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

getCodeBase() will give you the directory containing the class file, not the source. In jGRASP, unless you create a project with separate source and class directories, these will be the same. In other IDE's, this is usually not the case. Their default project configurations will have separate source and class directories. IntelliJ does seem to be putting them in the same directory though, since the modification times of source and class are the same, so that is apparently not the problem in this case. Most likely it is copying the class files somewhere else before launching the applet. You can display the value of getCodeBase() to find out where that is. I'm not too familiar with IntelliJ, but most likely you need to include the image file in the project in some way.